# OnTap Function in the DropDownMenu Button in Flutter

Tags: flutter, drop-down-menu, navigation, sqflite

I've tried to populate the dropdown menu button with the data from the SQLite database.
Then on the onTap Function I wanted to navigate to the selected category.

When I tap on the category it does not navigate.

I have saved each category with an id in the database which is used the identify the selected item.
Here is the code:

'''

```
class _HomeState extends State<Home> {

  TodoService _todoService;
  var _selectedValue;

  var _categories = List<DropdownMenuItem>();

  List<Todo>_todoList=List<Todo>();

@override
  initState(){
    super.initState();
_loadCategories();

  }

_loadCategories() async {
    var _categoryService = CategoryService();
    var categories = await _categoryService.readCategory();
    categories.forEach((category) {
      setState(() {
        _categories.add(DropdownMenuItem(
          child: Text(category['name']),
          value: category['name'],
          onTap: ()=>Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder:(context)=>TodosByCategory(category: category['name'],))),
        ));
      });
    });
  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _globalKey,
      appBar: AppBar(
        actions: <Widget>[
          DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
            child: DropdownButton(
              value: _selectedValue,
              items: _categories,
              dropdownColor: Colors.blue,
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 16.0),
              iconDisabledColor: Colors.white,
              iconEnabledColor: Colors.white,
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  _selectedValue = value;
                });
              },
            ),
          ),
```

'''

Here is the todosByCategory():

'''

```
class _TodosByCategoryState extends State<TodosByCategory> {

  List<Todo>_todoList=List<Todo>();

  TodoService _todoService=TodoService();

  @override
  initState(){
    super.initState();
    getTodosByCategories();
  }

  getTodosByCategories()async{
    var todos=await _todoService.readTodoByCategory(this.widget.category);
    todos.forEach((todo){
      setState(() {
        var model= Todo();
        model.title=todo['title'];
        model.dueDate=todo['dueDate'];

        _todoList.add(model);

      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Todos By Category'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: _todoList.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index){
              return Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top:8.0, left: 8.0, right: 8.0),
                child: Card(
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0),
                  ),
                  elevation: 8.0,
                  child: ListTile(
                    title: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(_todoList[index].title)
                      ],
                    ),
                    subtitle: Text(_todoList[index].dueDate),
//                    trailing: Text(_todoList[index].dueDate),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

'''
Please help me out.

Comment: When you tap on a category and it does not navigate, do you see any error in the console? If so, what is it?

Comment: No, there is no error on the console.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of writing the navigation code inside `onTap` of `DropdownMenuItem`, you can write it inside `onChanged` of `DropdownButton` where you are also getting the category name string as the `value`. It should work then.

Comment: -It does not work there because category is defined in _loadCategories

Comment: The `value` parameter which you get on `onChanged` is equal to the name of the category which you just tapped. So you can pass that to the next screen's constructor like this `TodosByCategory(category: value)`

Comment: Thanks! It worked, But did'nt get the category name at the top.