# How to Navigator.push() from a DropdownMenuItem's onTap and await the returned value?

Tags: flutter, dart

Following on from [Unhandled Exception: type '_DropdownRouteResult<int>' is not a subtype of type 'int?' when returning value from Navigator.pop()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73076016/unhandled-exception-type-dropdownrouteresultint-is-not-a-subtype-of-type) as I still haven't resolved the issue.

I have a `DropdownFormField` which I am dynamically populating from a db via a `Provider`.  I would like to add a `DropdownMenuItem` which, when selected, pushes a new route (for inserting a new record into the db).

The route returns the id of the newly-inserted db record when popped, and I would like to set the new value as the value of the `DropdownFormField`.

Implementing the new item with a `TextButton` child and pushing in the buttons' `onPressed` results in expected push/pop behaviour, but is styled inconsistently from the "normal" items, and does not close the dropdown (which makes sense as the button is pressed, but the `DropdownMenuItem` is not tapped).  Tapping outside the dropdown after popping reveals that the dropdown's value is updated correctly.

```dart
DropdownMenuItem<int>(child: TextButton(
        onPressed: () async {
          final int newValue = await Navigator.push(context, AddNewTeaProducerRoute());
          setState(() {
            _selectedValue = newValue;
          });
        },
        child: Text('Add New Manufacturer')));
```

Implementing the new item with a `Text` child and pushing in the `DropdownMenuItem`'s `onTap` (which seems like the correct approach) results in an immediate attempt to return the value, disrespecting the asynchronous nature of the `onTap` and resulting in the exception from my previous question.  Breakpoint debugging without specifying the type of `newValue` shows that it is immediately assigned the `Future`/`_DropdownRouteResult<int>`, rather than awaiting its returned `int`.

```dart
DropdownMenuItem<int>(
        onTap: () async {
          final int newValue = await Navigator.push(context, AddNewTeaProducerRoute());
          setState(() {
            _selectedValue = newValue;
          });
        },
        child: const Text('Add New Manufacturer'));
```

I have no idea why `await` is being respected in `TextButton.onPressed` but not in `DropdownMenuItem.onTap`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the *right* way, since it relies on `null` as a placeholder value and I can't see how you'd easily scale it beyond a single DropdownMenuItem with special behaviour (as unlikely as it seems that you'd want to) but after reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63015525/12476158) for the third time I finally grokked a solution - return null as the value, and perform navigation/assignment in the `DropdownButtonFormField`'s `onChanged`

```dart
final brokenAddNewTeaProducerButton = DropdownMenuItem<int>(
    value: null,
    child: const Text('Add New Manufacturer'));


return DropdownButtonFormField<int?>(
      value: _selectedValue,
      items: [brokenAddNewTeaProducerButton] + teaProducerListItems,
      onChanged: (value) async {
        if (value == null) {
          final newTeaProducerId = await Navigator.push(context, AddNewTeaProducerRoute());
          setState(() {
            _selectedValue = newTeaProducerId;
          });
        } else {
          setState(() {
            _selectedValue = value;
          });
        }
    },
      hint: Text('Select a manufacturer'),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
**You can try this statfulBuilder**

   StatefulBuilder(builder: (context,state){
                 return DropdownMenuItem<int>(child: TextButton(
                      onPressed: () async {
                        var newValue = await Navigator.push(context, 
    AddNewTeaProducerRoute());
                        state(() {
                          _selectedValue = newValue;
                        });
                      },
                      child: Text('Add New Manufacturer')));   
            }),
```